# Pandas read_sql_query with WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I am trying read data from SQL Server into a dataframe using pandas.read_sql_query. I have to set a condition where calendar year = 2020. I am using this syntax:

```
pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [abc] WHERE [calendarYear] = 2020', connectionObject)
```

I am getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UNKNOWN' to data
> type int.

Can anyone please help me with the syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `calendarYear` not an `int` type? I strongly suggest you make it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your calendarYear is a nvarchar so when you search only 2020 it throws an error. Try and put some '' around 2020 so your code would look like

```
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM [abc] WHERE [calendarYear] = '2020'", connectionObject)
```